# EF 4.1 Code First - model updated with [Required] attributes

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My model previously was without any DataNotations, but I recently changed that, applying [Required] for some properties. As this happen, my migration code start to throw an exception, like:

> Unable to apply pending changes because automatic migration is
>   disabled. To enable automatic migration, ensure that
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled is set to true.

I assume that some explicit actions of migration have to be done. Please clarify.

**EDIT**: AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true is not option for me, I'm interesting how to make it possible with some migration scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Configuration class extending  DbMigrationsConfiguration and set the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true, a sample class would look like this

```
namespace yournamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

        internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDbContext>
        {
            public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
                AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            }


        }
    }
```

then add the configuration class to the DbMigrator instance as follows

```
namespace yournamespace
{
    public class YourDataMigrator
    {
        public void MigrateData()
        {
            DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration=new Configuration();
            DbMigrator dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

            try
            {
                dbMigrator.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I think this would solve your problem

Comment: How to do same, without AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true option ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create migration scripts through the package manager console by executing the following scripts:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

followed by

```
PM> Add-Migration Initial
```

followed by

```
PM>  Update-Database
```

Originally found here: http://www.snippetsource.net/Snippet/146/enable-automatic-migrations-in-ef-codefirst-c

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am quite on the same page here, but I think this is what you are asking. I have AutomaticMigrations set to false:

```
public Configuration()
{
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

I have a Post class set like this:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

It is already generated, but then I realized for some reason I want title to be required.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I make the change, do a quick build, and then from the PM Console I type:

Add-Migration AddPostAnnotation (Name can be whatever you want)

This generates this file:

```
public partial class AddPostAnnotations : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Posts", "Title", c => c.String(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Posts", "Title", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

Once this is here, I just run Update-Database from the PM console, and the changes are sent over.